# Custom Document Filter - ClassNotFoundException when starting Connector

Tags: google-search-appliance, documentfilter

I am developing a custom document filter. So far I have created a project in eclipse, added jar files necessary and successfully built a jar file with my own document filter.

**What step am I missing to make the connector find the class ??**

When it comes to configuring the document filter in the file `'connectorInstance.xml'` something goes wrong and its seems the jar file cannot be found in the class path...

The Java package has the following classpath :

```
com.google.enterprise.connector.util.filter.DocFilterWildCardSearch
```

or also tried the following path

```
com.kapsch.gsa.filter.DocFilterWildCardSearch
```

I copied the `'DocFilterWildCardSearch.jar'` file into the following path:

```
C:\Program Files\GoogleConnectors\GSAConnectors1\Tomcat\webapps\connector-manager\WEB-INF\lib
```

*Restarted the connector and got the following error message:*

```
Nov 20, 2013 4:50:29 PM [Init] com.google.enterprise.connector.servlet.StartUp doStartup
SEVERE: Connector Manager Startup failed: 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'DocumentFilters' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/documentFilters.xml]: Cannot create inner bean 'asfsdf' of type [com.kapsch.gsa.filter.DocFilterWildCardSearch] while setting constructor argument with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [com.kapsch.gsa.filter.DocFilterWildCardSearch] for bean with name 'asfsdf' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/documentFilters.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.kapsch.gsa.filter.DocFilterWildCardSearch
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:230)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:117)
```

Config file for Document Filter : connectorInstance.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<beans>
    <bean class="com.example.connector.HelloWorldConnector" id="helloworld-connector"> </bean> 
    <bean class="com.google.enterprise.connector.util.filter.DocumentFilterChain" id="DocumentFilters"> 
    <constructor-arg>
    <list>
        <bean class="com.kapsch.gsa.filter.DocFilterWildCardSearch" id="asfsdf"> 
             <property value="Author" name="propertyName"/> 
             <property value="Roli" name="propertyValue"/> 
             <property value="false" name="overwrite"/> 
        </bean>
     </list>
     </constructor-arg> 
</bean>
</beans>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your settings are supposed to go inthe the documentFilters.xml file and not the connector instance file.

Google's got a support article on the subject [here](https://support.google.com/gsa/answer/2876080?hl=en) here.

It looks like you're attempting to nGram.  I've got a filter already that I've been meaning to open source.  If you would like it, drop me a note.

Finally, 7.2 is rumored to have wild carding in.  We won't know for sure until it comes out.

Comment: ,@bigmikew : both files can be used to configure a document filter - depending if you want to use it per connector instance or for all connectors...

Comment: Thanks Michael! If you could send me the filter to look at that would be great! drop me a mail to gsa-doc-filter@trashmail.net please so we can get in contact.

Comment: I can confirm the rumor - Mid December there will be a 7.2 version with wildcard search. (I did talk to Google about it on the phone, so first class source :-)

Answer (score 0):

Any chance you can include the output of jar tf on your doc filter jar file?

Michael is right in that you configure doc filters in documentfilters.xml.